# Maven build with Github Actions - Couldn't not resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I'm struggling a little bit with Github actions.

I'm trying to build a project with Maven using Github actions. The project contains a dependency located in a repo within the same org.

I created a PAT with read/write privileges and wrote the following script:

```
# This workflow will build a package using Maven and then publish it to GitHub packages when a release is created
# Added personal token

name: Maven Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: develop

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
        server-id: github
        
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file DynamoDB\ Service/pom.xml  
      env:
        MENADEX_USERNAME: my_username
        MENADEX_TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
    - name: Publish package
      run: mvn deploy -f DynamoDB\ Service/pom.xml -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/DynamoDB\ Service/settings.xml
      env:
        MENADEX_USERNAME: my_username
        MENADEX_TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Github keeps complaining it couldn't find the artifact related to the dependency.

**Settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>Common</id>
          <name>GitHub Menadex Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/Menadex/Ad360CommonObjects</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  
    <servers>
        <server>
          <id>github</id>
          <username>${env.MENADEX_USERNAME}</username>
          <password>${env.MENADEX_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

This is what I keep receiving:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dynamodb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ad360:dynamodb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.ad360:common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
210
[ERROR] 
211
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
212
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
213
[ERROR] 
214
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
215
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
216
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Also, I see that the newly created PAT was never touched. (In admin sections, it says 'never used').

Comment: Have you checked `https://maven.pkg.github.com/Menadex/Ad360CommonObjects`? Apart from that there are no public repositories at all? So how should that work?

Comment: The repos and packages are private and are supposed to be accessed with creds specified in the servers tag

Comment: This means otoh that the access does not work. Furthermore I doubt that the dependency are really SNAPSHOT's ...but I don't know that...apart from that your setup in GitHub actions (one with `package` and one with `deploy` means your are running several things duplicate etc. `) Furthermore why are you running from a sub directory and not from root of your project? That looks strange to me...